# Is it possible to change html page and display only selected iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, href, onload

In my website there are two main html pages. One is the home page (`index.html`), and the other one (`main.html`) is the one where I put several iframe elements displaying some other html pages that I have created.
First thing: is it possible to go from index.html to main.html (with an anchor element and an href attribute) AND ALSO having displayed ONLY SOME of the iframes in main.html?
Basically, I would like to click on a button in index.html and being simultaneously redirected to main.html but with only the first two iframes shown, while by clicking on the second button on index.html I go to main.html but only the last two iframes are shown this time.

Second thing:
In main.html a function `fun()` is called with `<body onload="fun()">` which retrives some kind of information from ALL the html pages sources of the iframe elements, even though not all the iframes are currently shown. It takes a lot of time though, so I thought that it would be better if `fun()` took as argument the id of the iframe to take the information from, depending on which button the user clicked on index.html.
As in the example above, I'd like to know if it is possible that by clicking on button 1 in index.html, I am redirected to main.html (as main.html was the value of an href attribute) BUT AT THE SAME TIME, since I clicked on button 1, only the first two iframes in main.html are shown AND `fun()` retrieves information ONLY from those two iframes (onload). Is it possible or am I just a dreamer?

Comment: Are you looking to send main some info which will tell it which iframes to display through the href string?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunatly your question does not meet the SO guidelines. Please take some time to take the SO tour, read the guidelines and edit your question accordingly. SO is neither a forum, tutorial nor a personal help desk. Its for specific coding issues only. Means that you already have some code you can provide and stuck at some point that cant be resolved with own research efford. If you have multiple questions, open multiple questions and do not ask those in the same topic.

Comment: Yes either through the href string or I don't know if there is a way to send that information through js, maybe some sort of a chain of js functions? Like one function may be triggered onclick on the anchor element linking to main, and that function may set the argument for another function which is responsible for displaying the specified/requested iframes in main.html .  But that would be that the two functions would be called consequently but in different html documents... I don't know if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

**Anchors**

Anchors are used to jump to a specific element with an unique ID. As such the link for that has to be:

```
<a href="#ID-Name"> Link Name </a>
```

If we think now about your index.html having an element with the ID `Test-Element` then the link for external page would be:

```
<a href="index.html#Test-Element"> Test-Element </a>
```

**:target**

target is a pseudo-selector for CSS to be used with anchors. You simply can hide all elements with `display: none;` and use `:target` to display only the element called with its anchor link.

```css
#Test-Box-green,
#Test-Box-blue,
#Test-Box-red {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: none;
}

#Test-Box-green {
  background-color: green;
}

#Test-Box-red {
  background-color: red;
}

#Test-Box-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#Test-Box-green:target {
  display: block;
}

#Test-Box-red:target {
  display: block;
}

#Test-Box-blue:target {
  display: block;
}

a div {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Test-Box-green"><div>Show green test box</div></a>
<a href="#Test-Box-blue"><div>Show blue test box</div></a>
<a href="#Test-Box-red"><div>Show red test box</div></a>

<div id="Test-Box-green"></div>
<div id="Test-Box-blue"></div>
<div id="Test-Box-red"></div>
```